# How to increase a css value, rather than concatenate it?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using this line:

```
$(this).css("z-index", z + 10);
```

The set z-index value is 1200.

edit: This is my variable `z = $(this).css("z-index");`

When debugging in the developer console I noticed that my z-index value was '120010' rather than the expected '1210'.

How can I change the above line to increase the value by 10, rather than concatenating the value to the end.

(Also am I using that word right? I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: You are using the correct word: to "concatenate" values is to join them together. You could also use "append," which in this context would mean to attach one string to the end of another string.

Comment: Thanks @BrandonGano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use the `parseInt()` function on your `z` variable. Something like this should work:

```
z = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
$(this).css("z-index", z + 10);
```

One thing to be careful about with this though, is that `z-index` can have a value that is not a number, for example `auto` If you run `parseInt()` on an element that's z-index is auto, it will break.

In order to combat this, I would recommend using `zIndex()` (part of jQuery UI) instead of `css()` like so:

```
z = $(this).zIndex();
$(this).css("z-index", z + 10);
```

This of course means you have to use jQueryUI, but if you are already using it, I'd recommend this approach.

EDIT: It looks like `zIndex()` has been removed from jQuery UI, so just stick to my first suggestion. http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#removed-zindex

Comment: Worked successfully, thank you. Will accept answer in 10 minutes,